Cannot migrate database to .NET 9.0
I initially ran the code and everything went fine, but when I tried to migrate it displayed the following:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.PendingModelChangesWarning

Stating that my ApplicationDB had pending changes when it doesn't.
The following presents the code for ApplicationDB:
public ApplicationDB(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDB> applicationDB): base(applicationDB) 
{
    public DbSet<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerModel> Customer { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DoctorModel> Doctor { get; set; } 
    
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Delete and rescaffold from the db? Run an apply if you assert there truly are no changes?

Are you seeding with non-deterministic values?

Do you have a [mre] you can share?

Ignore the warning? Seems like a known issue https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/34431
